# How to set string inside (click) function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to replace a string in a html element by a function name and in my case the string that i want to replace is inside a (click) function which it's seen as a function name not as a string but not also that when i get the HTML of the element the (click) function is not retrieved with it which i didn't know why . is there any way to make it happen ?

My html element

```
<li class="clearfix" (click)="fonction" style="cursor:pointer; 
   list-style: none;">
```

My function in component

```
var discussElt = document.getElementById('discussionElement').innerHTML;
   discussElt = discussElt.replace('fonction', 'clickDiscussion('  
                 + this.storage.get('discussTab')[i].id + ',' 
                 + this.storage.get('discussTab')[i].destinatorId + ")");
```

but the value of discussElt is

```
           <li class="clearfix" style="cursor:pointer;list-style: none;">
```

instead of `(click)="fonction"`

it will be `(click)="clickDiscussion(param1,param2)"`

Comment: You are using angular, so you should not be accessing html elements via the dom, especially not for something this simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the click event listener with if else to decide which function to execute instead of change the html ele by replace string.

```js
function func_1(event){
  //do something
  console.log("func_1 executed");
}

function func_2(event, param1, param2){
  //do something
  console.log("func_2 executed");
  console.log("param1 : " + param1);
  console.log("param2 : " + param2);
}

function click_healder_func(event){
  var execute_func = document.querySelector('#some_input').value; 
  var param1 = "par_1";
  var param2 = "par_2";
  if(execute_func == "func_1"){
      return func_1(event,);
  }else if(execute_func == "func_2"){
      return func_2(event, param1, param2);
  }
}
```

```html
type "func_2" in input then click li ele <input id="some_input" value="func_1"/>
<ol>
<li onclick="click_healder_func()" id="my_ele_id" class="clearfix" style="cursor:pointer; 
   list-style: none;"> i am li ele, click me</li></ol>
```

Comment: He is using angular ... he should not be accesing the dom at all for this

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelector('#liId').addEventListener('click',function(event){
  var param1 = this.storage.get('discussTab')[i].id ;
  var param2 = this.storage.get('discussTab')[i].destinatorId;

  return clickDiscussion(event, param1, param2);

});
```

and add an id to your

like this:

```
<li id="liId" class="clearfix" style="cursor:pointer;list-style: none;">
```

Ps: I used @yip102011 idea and applied it to your code